# What is background job queue in sql server? How to create a background job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-job

While exploring the SQL server I came up with following system tables:

```
sys.dm_exec_background_job_queue;
sys.dm_exec_background_job_queue_stats;
```

Official site tells that

It Returns a row for each query processor job that is scheduled for asynchronous (background) execution.

So how can I create a background (Asynchronous) jobs what will populate these system tables to see queued jobs in these tables or somewhere else?

PS: I am new to SQL Server I don't know if there is something like background job! Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Off-topic for SO - perhaps better fit for [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But even then, you need to learn about sql server in an organized fashion and not by just randomly choosing bits of interest. BTW - that's a view (not a table) and a part of DMVs.

Comment: Thanks SMor, will ask it on dba

Comment: From the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-background-job-queue-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it looks like it's for asynchronous statistics updates.